# Opening a modal after returning result of function yii 2

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii2

Hello is it possible to open a modal after getting results from a function? What I want to do is that I have a link button inside a modal then when clicked it passes some parameters to a function that will return a result.

Now I want to show the result in a another modal and close the previous modal, is this possible I've looked around the internet but I have not found a solution to my particular problem.

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-transparent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstyearmodal">
  <span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</button>


<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="firstyearmodal" role="dialog">
  <!--class="modal fade"-->
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <!--modal body-->
      <div class="modal-body">

        //this is the part where the user clicks the link then the modal fyft modal will show up
        <?=  HTML::a('<span style="font-size:1.5em;"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>',
                                           ['site/SubjectEquivalent', 'subjectcode' => $subjects['subjectcode']],
                                            ['data-method' => 'post']) ?>


          <!--end of modal body-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      <!--end of modal content-->
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--modal 1 for free section-->
  <!--First Year Modal-->
</div>



<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="fyftmodal" role="dialog">
  <!--class="modal fade"-->
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <!--modal body-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        //sample modal to show the process
        <!--end of modal body-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      <!--end of modal content-->
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--modal 1 for free section-->
  <!--First Year Modal-->
</div>
```

I found a similar code but it only touches on the css aspect and not the part where I am getting data.

http://jsfiddle.net/5qCm9/

**EDIT 1**

```
//controller
public function SubjectEquivalent($subjectcode){
      $model = new SubjectEquivalent();

     return $model->SubjectEquivalent($subjectcode);

    }




//view file and where the foreach method happens
 <?php foreach($firstyearfirstterm as $subjects):?>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Schedule</th>
                        <th>Section</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Slots</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Equivalent Subjects</th>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="width:130px">
                              <?= $subjects['subjectcode']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?= $subjects['schedday'] . ' ' . $subjects['schedtime'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $subjects['section'] ?></td>
                              <td style="width:130px">
                    <!--           base() -> site/function -->
                                   <!--  <a href="<?php // Url::base(); ?>test" class="btn-info btn-transparent btn-large">ADD</a> -->
                               <!-- SYNTAX - HTML::a('text', ['controller/function', 'value after /  of controller/function' => actual value],
                                              ['class' => 'class of the a component']) -->
                             <?php //if(ActiveSubject::find()->select(['clientid', 'subjectid'])
                                                                 // ->andWhere(['clientid' => $_user,])
                                                                //   ->andWhere(['subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],])):

                              /*  ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $_user,
                                                                     'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],])*/

                              //ActiveSubject::isAdded($_user, $subjects['subjectid'])
                             //Check if records exists in a table
                            $isAdded = ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $_user,'TrNo' => $subjects['TrNo'],])->exists();
                            $isFinished = FinishedSubjects::Checkprereq($subjects['TrNo'], $_user);
                            //read from subject container if exact sched is existing
                            //http://notepad.pw/samplees
                          //  $isConflict = ActiveSubject::find()->where(['schedday' => $subjects['schedday'],
                                                                //     'schedtime' => $subjects['schedtime']])->exists();
                                    if($isAdded):

                                 // ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $clientid,
                                 //                               'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],]);
                                 // echo ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid'  => $clientid, 'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid']])
                                 //                            ->createCommand()->sql;
                                 //make a function that returns a boolean form the activesubject model.see stackoverflow.
                                                                  ?>
                           <b class="text-muted"><p>ADDED</p></b>
                         <?php elseif($subjects['slots'] == 0 || $subjects['slots'] == $subjects['asqa']): ?>
                          <b class="text-muted">N/A</b>

                        <?php elseif($isFinished == false): ?>
                              <b class="text-muted">Pre requisite not completed</b>

                            <?php else: ?>

                                    <p>
                                      <?= Html::a('<b>ADD</b>',
                                         ['site/addsubject', 'TrNo' => $subjects['TrNo'], 'clientid' => $_user],
                                        ['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large', 'data-method' => 'post']) ?>
                                    </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>  <?= $subjects['slots'] ?> </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <?php if($isAdded): ?>
                               <b class="text-primary"><p>Awaiting Confirmation</p></b>
                            <?php elseif($isFinished == false): ?>
                              <b class="text-muted">Pre requisite not completed</b>
                             <?php elseif($subjects['slots'] == 0 || $subjects['slots'] == $subjects['asqa']): ?>
                              <b class="text-primary">No more slots</b>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><b class="text-primary">Approved: <?= $subjects['asqa']; ?></b></td>
                                    <td><b class="text-primary">&nbsp; Pending: <?= $subjects['astempqa']?></b></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                            <?php 
                            //This is where I wanted to show the modal for when i click the button then show the result another modal

                             //HTML::a('<span style="font-size:1.5em;"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>',
                                     //      ['site/SubjectEquivalent', 'subjectcode' => $subjects['subjectcode']],
                                       //     ['data-method' => 'post']) ?>
                           <!--    <a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="<?php // $subjects['subjectcode'] ?>">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
       <input type="text" name="bookId" value=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->



                            </p>                               
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        </table>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>

// This is what happens in the model (where the query should happen) don't mind the controller i just use it to pass through data.

<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class SubjectEquivalent extends ActiveRecord{
    public static function tableName(){
      return '{{%subjectequivalent}}';
  }

  public static function SubjectEquivalent($subjectcode){
    return static::find()
            ->where(['subjectmain' => subjectcode])
            ->asArray();
            ->all();
  }

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$("#close1_open2").click(function() {
var sum = parseInt($('#fnum').val(), 10)+parseInt($('#fnum').val(), 10);
$("#sum").text(sum);
    $("#modal1").modal('hide');
    $("#modal2").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">modal 1</button>

<div id="modal1" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>this is modal no. 1</p>
            <input type="text" id="fnum" />
            <input type="text" id="snum" />
            <button id="close1_open2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">close & open modal 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="modal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>sum of two number is : 
             <span id="sum"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes something like that but what I wanted to do was when I click "close & open modal 2" it will query a value from the database then show the result in another modal.

Comment: then you need to call web service inside 
$("#close1_open2").click(function() {
}

Comment: how do i do that? the value is dynamic from a foreach. so in my original implementation i am laying out the URL with parameters one by one from a foreach

Comment: can you tell me what the web method returns?